# What factors influence a successful iconv() TRANSLIT conversion?

Tags: php, iconv

I am trying to determine what environmental or other factors have an influence on the result of a call to `iconv()` with the `TRANSLIT` option.

The following code has different results for me locally when run through Apache and CLI.

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // for web     

    $utf8_string = "Pádraig's naïve café";

    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $utf8_string);
?>
```

Expected result: `Padraig's naive cafe`

Result in a web browser: `(empty string)`

Result from CLI: `P'adraig's na"ive cafe`

On some systems, I do get the expected result, but I can't tie down exactly why.

What factors influence the conversion, and what steps should I follow to increase the chance of a good result?

Comment: Your source file should be saved as a utf-8 file. Else your string will not actually be utf-8 even though you're telling iconv it is.

Comment: What systems do you get the right result no? Does it change if it's a Linux/Windows server?

Comment: Did you find the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locale *is* influencing `iconv` transliteration. However, you should read the warning on the [`setlocale`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/setlocale) manual page:

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called **setlocale()**. This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using **setlocale()**.

So you might set the locale but it's changed somewhere else. As long as the locale is exactly the same you will get the same results.

You find the documentation and the source-code of iconv here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/ - that's normally the library used by PHP.

Comment: As you can see from the code example, the locale is the same, yet the results are different.

Comment: You can not say if the locale is the same, because in the moment it is used it can be different. And there is no way for you to validate that. However, if you take a look into the source-code of libiconv you will see that it's based on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Is `setlocale` returning false? What os are you running?

You can try running `locale -a` on you box to see what locales are installed, `setlocale` should return the locale you specified.

Running your example above on centos with `en_GB.UTF-8` in the `locale -a` list returns the expected result.

Comment: `setlocale` returns `en_GB.UTF-8`. This is on Mac OS X 10.7.3.